# Why does a variable with the unary operator ++ in JavaScript not change the variable by 1 until the next appearance of the variable inside brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

I know that in C, C++, Java, etc, there is a difference between foo++ and ++foo. In JavaScript, there is no ++foo, and JavaScript's foo++ *usually* behaves like C's ++foo:

```
var x = 10;
x++;
console.log(x); //11
```

But here:

```
var x = 0;
var w = "012345";
console.log(w[x++]); //0
console.log(w[x++]); //1
```

...It behaves like C's foo++?

Comment: When placed after an expression, `++` is a [*Postfix Increment Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator). When placed before a unary expression, it's a [*Prefix Increment Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-prefix-increment-operator). `--` is the equivalent prefix/postfix decrement operator. Neither are [unary operators](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-unary-operators).

Comment: `JavaScript's foo++ usually behaves like C's ++foo` - I think you made a mistake in this statement ... the correct version is *JavaScript's foo++ **never** behaves like C's ++foo* - or alternatively *JavaScript's foo++ **always** behaves like C's foo++*

Comment: @JaromandaX  then how do you explain the above result? ( Try it if you don't believe me)

Comment: the above results are correct. first code, x will be 11 before you console.log it ... the post-increment takes place then you console.log ... if you `console.log(x++)` you will get `10` not `11` - post-increment doesn't wait until an arbitrary time later to change x within the statement it is executed ... which is `x++`

Comment: no, I mean the second box; the first one is perfectly fine, the second one is a little more perplexing.

Comment: @RaphaelSpoerri—in the second case, `x++` logs 0, **then** increments *x*. Then it logs 1 and increments *x* again (so next time it will be 2). *Prefix increment* means increment, then evaluate the expression. *Posfix increment* means evaluate the expression, then increment. In both cases, the value is incremented before the next expression is evaluated. The difference is the value used in the expression involving the operator.

Comment: You need to show an example at which the `++x` and `x++` behaves differently to another language. (Show a [mcve] in js and the other language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Jack Bashford, I think I understand it:

The reason I asked this question is because I misunderstood what "increment after using" meant; I thought it meant at the next statement, it really means immediately after the expression. I also got confused because JavaScript has a few conventions about when to use `++`. In conclusion, C's ++ and JavaScript's ++ work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

> In JavaScript, there is no ++foo

That's wrong. There *is* a pre-increment operator, and it works like this:

```js
var x = 0;
var w = "012345";
console.log(w[++x]); //1
console.log(w[++x]); //2
```

Comment: Oh, you' re right! that's so weird, because the reason most likely never seen ++x is because there is usually no difference, except for here.

Comment: Yes - in a normal `for` loop you'd usually use `i++` rather than `++i` (although for performance `+=` is better).

Comment: can somebody, though, explain the weirdness of w[x++]?

Comment: There is no weirdness - it's equivalent to `console.log(w[x]); x += 1;`.

Comment: true, since x++ is a form of assignment, but why does it interpreted as simply x the first time **and then incremented the second time?**

Comment: if both x++ and ++x are forms of assignment, then why does x++ work as an expression and an assignment?

Comment: `x++` returns the value of `x`, *then* increments `x`. `++x` increments `x`, *then* returns the value of `x`. Logical given the placement of the operator.

Comment: I know @RobG, it's just preference.

Comment: Oh, I think I get your point, since x++ and ++x are not usually used in JavaScript as expressions.

Comment: No, they're usually assignments - they're shorthand for +=.

Comment: Your answer is true, though, but it doesn't answer the question.